# Transverse a graph using Hamiltonian cycles

Tags: algorithm, graph, nodes, cycle

Let's say we're given a graph and we want to find the minimum number of Hamilton cycles that are required to transverse each node of the graph.

If the graph has 6 nodes and we have edges:

```
1-2
2-3
3-1
3-4
4-5
5-6
6-4
```

Obviously the minimum number of Hamiltonian cycles is 2 (1-2-3 and 4-5-6).

The only idea I have is to check whether there is 1 Hamiltonian cycle that transverse the whole graph. If there isn't check for 2 and so on. But this is time consuming and also it could happen that a particular node can be part of 2 different Hamiltonian cycles, so we might have trouble choosing in which cycle shoud we incude it.

The number of nodes in the graph is N(N<=50), while the numer of edges can go as high as n(n-1)/2

Comment: This problem is NP-Complete. And a [Hamiltonian cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) visits **every node** exactly once, so what you're looking for are not Hamiltonian cycles.

Comment: Can you please clarify question, sounds like an interesting problem?

Comment: @Riko Well we have an undirected unweighted graph. It is possible to pick a random node and make a Hamiltonian cycle and come back to the same node, visiting some number of nodes on the way. Now if we haven't visited some of the nodes it is also possible to do that for them. Each such step means that we have found a Hamiltonian cycle. We need to minimize their number